# The time complexity of integral evaluation

Tags: numerical-methods, approximate-integration

I have the following integral:

$$p(x) = \int p(\pmb{\mu})\prod_{i=1}^n\sum_{c_i}p(c_i)p(x_i|c_i,\pmb{\mu})d\pmb{\mu}$$ $\pmb{\mu} \in \mathbf{R}^K$ . The time complexity to numerically evaluate this integral is $\mathcal{O}(K^n)$ but I am not sure how this number is obtained?

Comment: Assuming that $c_i$ belongs to one of $K$ classes, then the integrand is the sum of $K^n$ terms, so it would stand to reason that computing $p(x)$ requires one to evaluate $K^n$ (multiple) integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to understand the same and arrived here haha.
I think a good way to see it, is to decompose the integral.

$$ p(x) = \int p(\mu)\prod^{n}_{i=1}(f_{i,\mu_1}+f_{i,\mu_2}+..+f_{i,\mu_k})$$

Imagine $n=1$, In this case, to numerically evaluate the integral we have $K$ terms and the complexity is $O(K)$.

Now with $n=2$ we have

$$ p(x) = \int p(\mu)(f_{1,\mu_1}+f_{1,\mu_2}+..+f_{1,\mu_k})(f_{2,\mu_1}+f_{2,\mu_2}+..+f_{2,\mu_k})
$$

Then,for each new sample that you add, you are multiplying the number of terms by $K$ and the complexity of $n$ number of samples is $O(K^n)$.